# Is there any way I can make my function for testing the equality of strings even faster?

Tags: c, performance

I want to learn how to write faster code in C, so I've written and am continuously optimising a function that tests the equality of two strings.

```
int stringsequal(register char *s1, register char *s2)
{
    do
    {
        if(!(*s1 ^ 0)) return 1;
    }
    while(!(*(s1 ++) ^ *(s2 ++)));
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to your feedback I have improved my code! Here is my new code:

```
int stringsequal(register char *s1, register char *s2)
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(!((*s1 + *s2) ^ 0)) return 1;
        if(*(s1 ++) ^ *(s2 ++)) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: If I could delete this question, I would, sorry for wasting your time everyone.

Comment: Did you first check if `strcmp` from the standard library isn't "fast enough"?

Comment: Perhaps use memcmp() instead of strcmp()?

Comment: @StoryTeller This is just a little side project I've been working on today to help me learn how to write faster code in C. It's not in any way intended to replace strcmp() in the standard library, I just want to know if further improvement is possible.

Comment: When improving, one needs a benchmark and something to improve *over*. I asked about the standard library version because it's already optimized to death, so writing it "faster" is an exercise in futility. If however, you are improving over the naive version, then that's something else. You better add those details in your question. The title really doesn't say all.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'll edit the question then

Comment: What are you optimizing for? Latency, throughput, O-complexity?

Comment: @RickMoritz I actually don't know. I started out trying to avoid using local-scope variables and once I realised I could, I started trying to optimise for time.

Comment: What's the thinking behind `(*s1 ^ 0)`?

Comment: @user3386109 That statement returns 0 if the current index of the string being examined is the null-terminator character of a C string. Essentially, if I were to test against the character '\0' it would be equivalent anyway, so I skipped a step and tested against the position of the null-terminator character instead.

Comment: Back when I learned C and saw my first optimized bits of code, everything was about reducing forks/branches. With speculative execution and branch prediction this has become less of an issue, and the compiler will usually unroll well written loops for you. But the compiler will often optimize away local variables, if it can, so you first have to define test cases, since there is no generally optimal code. I think the two most valuable optimizations these days are using parallel processing, and SIMD/streaming instructions. Try writing your code based on a vector library, if you want throughput

Comment: Did something lead you to believe xor is faster than !=?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Isn't it?

Comment: @JosephPilliner: anything xor’d with zero yields the value of anything.  It’s likely the compiler will omit the xor operation.  While I’ve not pored over instruction speeds, it is unlikely that xor and not equal are different in speed.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own post.  You cannot delete it because you accepted an answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison my question was pointless, and the answers rightly pointed out that it was a stupid thing to ask. What makes you believe it has any value to anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first function just do not work and is wrong.

You do not the correct parameter types. Do not use `register` as it has no effect at all. Register is ignored at any level of optimization. Compilers are better than me or you in micro optimizations - so help the compiler optimizer with the `const` and `restrict` when applicable.

The second one can be simplified.

```
int stringsequal1(const char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2)
{
    do
    {
        if(*s1 != *s2) return 0;
    }
    while(*s1++ + *s2++);
    return 1;
}
```

and thew result code for both is:

```
int stringsequal1(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    do
    {
        if(*s1 != *s2) return 0;
    }
    while(*s1++ + *s2++);
    return 1;
}

stringsequal1:
        xor     edx, edx
        jmp     .L11
.L15:
        add     rdx, 1
        add     eax, eax
        je      .L14
.L11:
        movsx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi+rdx]
        cmp     al, BYTE PTR [rsi+rdx]
        je      .L15
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
.L14:
        ret

int stringsequal2(register char *s1, register char *s2)
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(!((*s1 + *s2) ^ 0)) return 1;
        if(*(s1 ++) ^ *(s2 ++)) break;
    }
    return 0;
}

stringsequal2:
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     .L18
.L22:
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     cl, r9b
        jne     .L21
.L18:
        movsx   r8d, BYTE PTR [rdi+rax]
        movsx   r9d, BYTE PTR [rsi+rax]
        mov     ecx, r8d
        add     r8d, r9d
        jne     .L22
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
.L21:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can make my function for testing the equality of strings even faster?

Faster is better, but not if it breaks functionally.  Else code might as will be

```
// Faster but wrong functionally
int stringsequal0(register char *s1, register char *s2) {
  return 0;
}
```

Both of OP's `strcequal()` are functionally flawed.  The first reports `strequal("", any_string)` as equal and the 2nd will report as equal any time the `char`s add to 0.  (Consider a `char` in one string with a negative value).

Faster way: Yes.  Rather than call your own for `strequal()`, either call the standard library function `strcmp()` or look to model code after one of its implementation.

Conceptually, only compares needed in the loop are `*s1 == *s2` and `*s1 == 0`.  `*s2 == 0` is **not** needed in the loop.

```
inline /* or don't inline */ int strequal1(const char *a, const char *b) {
  return strcmp(a,b)==0;
}

int strequal2(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  while (*s1 && *s1 == *s2) {
    s1++;
    s2++;
  }
  return *s1 == *s2;
}
```

In the end, only profiling will determine which is "faster".  Recall, one approach may be faster with small and unlikely-math strings, while another approach may perform better with long strings the rarely differ.

Compilers are smart and crafty.  Optimization compilers can analyze code and replace a calls like `strcmp(s, "abc")==0` will a single 4-byte compare.  Note that compilers can "cheat" and perform things, regular C code cannot rely on.  The  compiler may not as well understand your `strequal()` to take similar advantages.

I doubt *very much* OP can roll a solution that significantly out-performs `strcmp()` with long similar strings.

Comment: @P__J__ The link presents emitted code for  a select processor - maybe matching OP's or not.  While smaller code is often faster, it does not demo improve speed.  OP is looking for faster code yet is using a broken reference.  We lack a test set of strings too.  Should similar strings tend to be large, multi-byte compares tend to win such profiling - yet required more set up code and often some assumptions about object layout.

Comment: You can test on other platforms as well. Less memory access is the point here

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying, but characters cannot have a negative value without said value being set manually

Comment: @JosephPilliner `char`, on common systems that employ a signed `char`, can have negative values without _manually_ setting them.  Code can create strings at compile and run time with negative `char` elements, as well as by user input.  Sure it is less common than positive values, but   not impossible - especially in the realm of hostile user input.  No one wants their code to be the next hacker exploit.

Comment: @chux I've fixed that now by declaring in the header that the inputted strings must be arrays of unsigned chars

Comment: If you think characters can't be negative then you've never dealt with utf-8.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're current code, does not do strcmp functionality.
The loop

```
 while(!(*(str1 ++) ^ *(str2 ++)));
```

does nothing.

The strcmp return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if str1 is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than str2.

your method returns 1 or zero, and does not match strcmp specification.

Beside this, I think strcmp is already optimized. using memcmp won't give better performance, is you'll need first know the length of str1, and str2. so you'll need to pass all string characters for both str1 and str2 strings.

here the implementation of glibc.

```
int STRCMP (const char *p1, const char *p2)
{
  const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char *) p1;
  const unsigned char *s2 = (const unsigned char *) p2;
  unsigned char c1, c2;

  do
    {
      c1 = (unsigned char) *s1++;
      c2 = (unsigned char) *s2++;
      if (c1 == '\0')
        return c1 - c2;
    }
  while (c1 == c2);

  return c1 - c2;
}
```

Comment: I have corrected my question and changed the function name to better reflect its purpose. Also, I have tested the code and it does work in so far as I'm aware.

Comment: try for example str1="abc", str2="abcd"

Comment: Apologies, I was mistaken.

Comment: your function is the UB wen first string is longer than the second. You will read out of bounds of the second one